# Vertx slows down with multiple file upload requests

Tags: java, vert.x

i am trying to create a large scaled file server (2 millions concurrent) and after lots of search i found out that Vertx is best for such tasks . so i came up with this piece of code

```
    public void uploadFile(Vertx vertx,RoutingContext ctx,String targetFilePath,FileUploadListener mListener) {
         ctx.request().pause();

         new File(targetFilePath).getParentFile().mkdirs();

          vertx.fileSystem().open(targetFilePath, new OpenOptions(), new Handler<AsyncResult<AsyncFile>>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(AsyncResult<AsyncFile> arg0) {
                try {
                    AsyncFile file = arg0.result();
                    if(file == null) {
                        Logger.Log("file null");
                        mListener.onFail();
                        return;
                    }
                    Pump pump = Pump.pump(ctx.request(), file);

                    ctx.request().endHandler(v1 -> file.close(v2 -> {
                                mListener.onSuccess(new File(targetFilePath));
                    }));
                    pump.start();
                    ctx.request().resume();

                }catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Logger.Log(e);
                    mListener.onFail();
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

how ever when multiple requests try to concurrently upload a file using this method (takes 1 second for a 9mb file , but takes 1 minute for 100 of 9mb files) the upload process slows down .is there some thing that im missing for improving concurrency or since im running this on Windows 10 , a socket has such speed limit ? thanks

here is my MainVerticle

```
 public class MainDeployment extends AbstractVerticle{


private Router router = Router.router(vertx);

  @Override
  public void start() throws Exception {

      //GUI.display("Sub Verticle Has Deployed");

    // Different ways of deploying verticles

    // Deploy a verticle and don't wait for it to start

   for(Entry<String, MyHttpHandler> entry : MyVertxServer.map.entrySet()){
       router.route(entry.getKey()).handler(new Handler<RoutingContext>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(RoutingContext ctx) {
                System.out.println(ctx.request().uri());

                String[] handlerID = ctx.request().uri().split(ctx.currentRoute().getPath());

                String suffix = handlerID.length > 1 ? handlerID[1] : null;
                entry.getValue().Handle(ctx, new VertxUtils(), suffix);

            }
        });
   }

   MyVertxServer.server.requestHandler(router::accept);

  }

}
```

Comment: I wonder how do you upload that 100 files. Using the same machine, maybe? And does your Vertx runs on the same machine? And since you mentioned WIndows 10, maybe you even have single HDD?

Comment: all true :) , so does it mean any thing making my day happy ?

Comment: plus all being uploaded using same client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code looks fine. Your testing methodologies are not. This has nothing to do with Vertx, actually.
First, uploading from the same machine you use for downloading (Vertx from its perspective downloads files you upload) reduces the amount of resources available to Vertx by half. You have what, 4 CPUs, probably? 2 of them will be busy uploading, and only other two will be serving your requests.

Then there's the network. Actually, I'm amazed you're able to upload 9Mb in a second. That's some serious network there.

And of course there's HDD. I hope for the sake of your experiment that you upload a file that you cached in memory. Otherwise, you have 100 processes now reading this file again and again, while other 100 try to write it. Even if you have top-notch SSDs, that's quite a challenge.

So, having said all that, you need to do the math now. First, deploy your code to a different machine than your client.

Comment: dont be amazed , its being uploaded through local host :)
and yes your right  thanks for making my day as i wished :) so i need a better experiental environment